# Change display language in Windows 10 with CMD or PowerShell commands

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell

How can I use either CMD or PowerShell to change the display language only, for all users in a Windows 10 Pro?

*I would rather avoid using any external ps1 file or batch file. I have seen some solutions that require you to use  XML files or a PS1 scripts. But I would prefer if there is a cmdlet or just a couple of commands that can do this without having to download any script files.*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Consider using the [`Set-WinSystemLocale`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/set-winsystemlocale?view=win10-ps) and/or 
[`Set-WinUserLanguageList`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/set-winuserlanguagelist?view=win10-ps) **PowerShell** cmdlets right from the **PowerShell** command line or IDE with no script and with a couple simple commands.

---

### Commands

**Note:** *Be sure to replace `en-US` with the language/locale for your need.*

```
Set-WinSystemLocale en-US
Set-WinUserLanguageList en-US
```

---

### Further Resources

- [Set-WinSystemLocale](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/set-winsystemlocale?view=win10-ps)
- [Set-WinUserLanguageList](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/set-winuserlanguagelist?view=win10-ps)
- [International Settings Cmdlets in Windows PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852115.aspx)

Comment: So I tested this in a VM and it seems to work very well. Only caveat is that the language you add will have to be downloaded from the Control Panel after the commands which sort of defeats the purpose of one-liners I guess.

Comment: Does this change the language permanently or just one session (I would test this myself but I'm not on windows)