# Change Windows Display Language (Windows 10) - Local Experience Packs (LXPs) - via CMD/Powershell

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell

I want to add an Local Experience Pack and change the default Windows Display Language via CMD/Powershell.

[image: Windows Display Language]

I came across
[Change display language in Windows 10 with CMD or PowerShell commands](https://superuser.com/questions/1309399/change-display-language-in-windows-10-with-cmd-or-powershell-commands)

But this only shows me how to change the default language of the OS.
It does not actually change the Language of the UI Elements in Windows.

I also came across some articles which explain the new concept of Microsoft with local experience packs
https://4sysops.com/archives/local-experience-packs-add-languages-to-windows-10-and-server-2019/

I have an Azure Virtual Machine and I want to automate the installation of the Local Experience Packs (LXPs) via the Windows Store. A manual installation is not an option.

Is there a possibility to do so?

**Update 07th January 2021:**

Get-WinUserLanguageList gives me

```
LanguageTag : de-DE
Autonym : Deutsch (Deutschland) 
EnglishName : German 
LocalizedName : German (Germany) 
ScriptName : Latin 
InputMethodTips : {0407:00000407} 
Spellchecking : True 
Handwriting : False
```

The UI of the OS is still in English.

```
Set-WinSystemLocale de-DE
```

does not change that either.

Comment: How about in this order try both elevated as administrator and maybe not as well to see if either make any difference: `Set-WinUILanguageOverride de-DE; Set-WinSystemLocale de-DE; Set-WinUserLanguageList de-DE;` in that specific order trying both elevated and not. If this helps, I'll be happy to make an answer for the bounty for you. Please tag me back and let me know either way. I'd rather not make an answer though if it does not fix the problem but if it does, the issue is likely the order of those commands run.

Comment: it looks like you might actually need to download the LXP to a local share and then use the `Add-ProvisionedAppXPackage` cmdlet. It's talked about some here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/17257410-8561-4327-8b55-2eab4a1e3cbb/installdeploy-local-experience-pack-in-enterprise?forum=win10itprogeneral too. That sysops link you have shows some examples too. You might just have to figure out how to get the `.\LanguageExperiencePack.de-DE.Neutral.appx` from a machine you have it and then use that copy for further mass deployment. Quick thoughts just get from a machine it's on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article
[Local Experience Packs: Add languages to Windows 10 and Server 2019](https://4sysops.com/archives/local-experience-packs-add-languages-to-windows-10-and-server-2019/)
says that the PowerShell command to use is
[Set-WinUILanguageOverride](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/set-winuilanguageoverride?view=win10-ps),
like this:

```
Set-WinUILanguageOverride -Language de-DE
```

A complete language manipulation script is included in the TechNet article
[How to change display language in Windows 10 (change/install LP/remove LP)](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-change-display-80448f7f)
that implements multiple verbs that you would find useful.
For changing the display language, the verb is `SetLanguage`
and the script should be called like this:

```
 C:\Script\ChangeSystemDisplayLanguage.ps1 –SetLanguage "de-DE"
```

A look into the source code shows that this verb uses four other commands
instead of the `Set-WinUILanguageOverride` command.
An adaptation specific to German of these commands as
lifted from the script's `SetLanguage` option would give something like:

```
$SetLanguage = "de-DE"
$GeoId = 0x5e               <# Germany #>
Set-Culture $SetLanguage
Set-WinSystemLocale $SetLanguage
Set-WinHomeLocation $GeoId
Set-WinUserLanguageList $SetLanguage -force
```

These four commands may be equivalent to `Set-WinUILanguageOverride`,
or may not, so you could select according to your needs.

Comment: Unfortunately both options did not work. I also tried a restart after executing the commands. May be the script works only with Windows 10 Versions before Windows 10 1803, Where Microsoft has begun to replace language packs (LPs) in .cab format with Local Experience Packs (LXPs). Is there a way to automatically download the LXPs from the Microsoft Store?

Comment: See [How to Download APPX Installation File from Microsoft Store in Windows 10 / 8.1](http://woshub.com/how-to-download-appx-installation-file-for-any-windows-store-app/). Or the very similar [How to Download APPX file of Any App from Windows Store](https://windowsloop.com/how-to-download-appx-file-of-any-app-from-windows-store/).

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the APPX Installation hint. I will mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime it is also possible as an alternative to install the language pack via powershell:

```
Install-Language de-DE
Set-SystemPreferredUILanguage de-DE
```

Requirement for this is Windows 10 20H2 and above or Windows 11